# Chrome spending a lot of time stalled

Tags: networking, google-chrome, http

This happens sporadically when requesting a page.  I haven't seen it occur while loading other items within a page.  So it seems to be isolated to making a new request or refreshing the current page.

[image]

From the [explanation link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing):

[image]

How can I tell what Chrome is actually trying to do so that I can continue troubleshooting? I've tested using Firefox and Edge as well. Neither exhibit similar connectivity problems.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem :(

Disabled all extensions, created a new user, disabled Microsoft EMET.

Disk usage, CPU load, and network is fine